# Bootstrap on Phonegap cannot be responsive

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I just ran a simple hello world test and noticed that the text and images are much smaller than I expected.

I soon realised this is because Phonegap is displaying the webpages as if the phones resolution was the same as a computer. I quickly checked this by alerting the width and height and sure enough the width was 1080px and the height was around 1900px.

Now when I view a bootstrapped website and do a similar alert through the native browser it will tell me that my screen is somewhere closer to the 400px width mark and accordingly change the template.

So why does Phonegap display the app/webpage as if the dip was the actual pixel density therefore everything is much much smaller.